# will_paginate only show previous_page & next_page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, pagination, will-paginate

I don't want to list out the number of each page. How can we just show "previous" and "next" with `will_paginate`?

**view**

```
<%= will_paginate @activities %>
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  etc...
<% end %>
```

**controller**

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @activities = Activity.order("created_at desc").where(user_id: current_user.following_ids).paginate(:page => params[:page])
    end
end
```

**model**

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.per_page = 25

  def page_number
    (index / per_page.to_f).ceil
  end

  private

  def index
    Activity.order(created_at: :desc).index self
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this in your view?

```
<%= will_paginate @activities, :page_links => false %>
```

From the docs here ( http://mislav.github.io/will_paginate/ ) it looks like that might be what you're looking for